# bootstrap error in juju 1.25

Tags: juju, maas

Using juju 1.25 when I tried to bootstrap it hangs and gives error after waiting a long time:

juju version
1.25.3-trusty-amd64

```
"Attempt 5 to download tools from https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/agent/1.25.3/juju-1.25.3-trusty-amd64.tgz...
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: streams.canonical.com
tools from https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/agent/1.25.3/juju-1.25.3-trusty-amd64.tgz downloaded: HTTP 000; time 0.000s; size 0 bytes; speed 0.000 bytes/s sha256sum: /var/lib/juju/tools/1.25.3-trusty-amd64/tools.tar.gz: No such file or directory
2016-03-29 15:22:06 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:429 failed to bootstrap environment: subprocess encountered error code 1"
```

When trying to check the status it gives this error:
 juju status

ERROR Unable to connect to environment "maas".
Please check your credentials or use 'juju bootstrap' to create a new environment.

```
Error details:
unable to connect to "wss://192.168.15.193:17070/environment/720c0c1c-d2b2-412e-8b57-ac2aa1e5463f/api"
```

There was a thread earlier on this:

[juju Bootstrap --debug failed to connect https://streams.canonical.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465508/juju-bootstrap-debug-failed-to-connect-https-streams-canonical-com)

I have tested it. There is no firewall on the server and its a standalone machine. I have checked the resolver and DNS server settings and it appears to be fine. Can some one help me with this error ?